# Unkown Key in Elasticsearch Template

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i'm using elasticsearch 7.6.1 for my project, I want to create index template elasticsearch with http-index_template but when i try PUT index mapping like this :

> curl -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/json'
>   http://my-ip:9200/_template/http-index_template?pretty -d
>   @http-index_template.json

it says :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "unknown key [http-index_template] in the template "
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "unknown key [http-index_template] in the template "
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

when i try to change **my-ip** to **localhost** it says:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

so whats problem here and how to fix this?

http-index_template.json :

```
{
    "http-index_template": {
        "order": 0,
        "template": "http-index*",
        "settings": {},
        "mappings": {
            "http-log": {
                "properties": {
                    "referer": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "request": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "virtual": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "method": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "version": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "response_size": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "client_port": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "hostname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "syslog_hostname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "port": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "syslog_timestamp": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "@version": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "server_ip": {
                        "type": "ip"
                    },
                    "client_ip": {
                        "type": "ip"
                    },
                    "response_time": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "server_port": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "User-Agent": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "aliases": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your template file, remove the outer entry `http-index_template`, (and in ES 7 you should remove index type `http-log`)

```
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "http-index*",
  "settings": {},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "referer": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "request": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "virtual": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "method": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "version": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "response_size": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "client_port": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "hostname": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "syslog_hostname": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "port": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "syslog_timestamp": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "host": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "server_ip": {
        "type": "ip"
      },
      "client_ip": {
        "type": "ip"
      },
      "response_time": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "server_port": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "User-Agent": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {}
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer my question. It says this when i trying to use your template : [mapper_parsing_exception](https://pastebin.com/2BzXmFHi)

Comment: @s1gnific4nt, sorry, I remove the index type from template, try on ES 7.5 and it works fine